# UIDatePicker is returning with instantiated dateTime's seconds in all dates..?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

The date returned from a UIDatePicker includes seconds. Why? If I select the date "Today, 1:07 pm" and click a button to print out the selected date, I get `2019-06-13 13:07:07 +0000`. If I change the date to something else, I get e.g `2019-06-14 14:35:07 +0000`. Why are those `:07` seconds present? Still the same seconds. If I run the app again, it might be some completely different seconds.
It seems as it stores the number of seconds since the datePicker was initialized, for some reason. So if I restart the app at `14:07:34`, then all the times selected in the datePicker will show `xx:xx:34`. Always the same seconds throughout its lifetime.

The documentation states `date: The date displayed by the date picker.` These seconds are not displayed. Why are these seconds included?

How do I prevent the datepicker from returning these useless seconds? They are actually making it so people miss their bus, in our case.

I know I can do a "workaround" by flatting the resulting date to remove its seconds, but this feels like it's either a bug or a setting I don't know about.

Comment: never experience this, did you tried in real device? or simulator. i think it will work fine in Appstore build.

Comment: @Ajumal We found out about it because a customer reported something fishy with the dates. I'll try a sample project on a real device when I get the time.

Comment: @Ajumal Tried it now, still happens on real device.

Answer (score 0):

From the `UIDatePicker.h` file:

```
// default is current date when picker created. 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
```

This is the hint to different seconds on each instance of date picker.

`UIDatePicker` just fulfils its datasource forwards and backwards from the current time when it is instantiated.

In order to make proper flooring of the date in the way you like, assign to the `date` property the value which is floored, and `picker` will report results with the same flooring.